# What is the short story about a plasma creature hitting Mercury?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

When I was young I read a short story about a creature made of plasma ejected from the sun by a solar flare. It flew through space and hit the boiling hot sun-facing side of Mercury, whereupon it 'froze' to death. It blew my mind.
I thought it was from Arthur C Clarke, but I can't seem to find it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When were you young?

Comment: Your description of the story was, at least for me, sadly more enthralling than the actual story itself.

Comment: @Nit - Sacrilege :-(

Comment: @Nit I thought it was a fantastic story. I prefer hard-scifi and Sir Clarke certainly knew his science. Like I said before, the idea contained in the story totally blew my mind.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The story you're describing is "[Out of the Sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Collected_Stories_of_Arthur_C._Clarke)" by Arthur C Clarke.

> We were looking at what seemed to be a translucent oval, its interior
>   laced with a network of almost invisible lines. Where the lines
>   crossed, there appeared to be tiny, pulsing nodes of light; we could
>   never be quite sure of their existence because the radar took almost a
>   minute to paint the complete picture on the screen—and between each
>   sweep the object moved several thousand miles. There was no doubt,
>   however, that the network itself existed; the cameras settled any
>   arguments about that.

later

> Then the radar screen was empty, wiped clean during a single scan of
>   the beam. The creature had fallen below our horizon, and was hidden
>   from us now by the curve of the planet. Far out in the burning dayside
>   of Mercury, in the inferno where only a dozen men have ever ventured
>   and fewer still come back alive, it smashed silently and invisibly
>   against the seas of molten metal, the hills of slowly moving lava. The
>   mere impact could have meant nothing to such an entity what it could
>   not endure was its first contact with **the inconceivable cold of solid
>   matter.**

Comment: Brilliant, that's it exactly. I just reread it. Wow! It just as powerful as I remember. Cheers!