# Short story: man stranded on Mars, hears clacking sound

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I would like to recall the name of a story I read long back, it goes like:

On a Martian mission a man gets stranded somewhat far from the base as his vehicle breaks down. He decides to walk back he goes along a canyon, as he passes a particular spot (noted earlier in the story for its geographical features of containing polished stones or some such things) he hears a clacking sound.

Comment: [What is the short story about a plasma creature hitting Mercury?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56021/what-is-the-short-story-about-a-plasma-creature-hitting-mercury)

Comment: [Man travelling alone across a planet, thinks about a fearsome creature that he hears behind him](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73336/man-travelling-alone-across-a-planet-thinks-about-a-fearsome-creature-that-he-h)

Comment: Are your 1) and 2) two separate stories? If so, you should open two separate questions to ask about them.

Comment: @randal'thor - They are indeed separate stories. Both dupes.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing out the off-topic part of your question (in order to forestall further close-votes; there are 2 already), and then upvoted. I still suggest that you open two questions rather than one to ask about your two separate stories, unless they're both the stories Richard has already mentioned.

Comment: Sorry I thought asking suggestions would not be a problem. It is not if one asks for a list of references on math.stack. I am reviewing the two stories now.

Comment: For the record, I voted to close as "Too Broad", not "Off Topic".  2 questions in one post is one question  too many.

Comment: Moderation is too strict here! Swift like the King Solomon's sword! :)

Comment: @randal'thor: It seems you were too slow. Now, we are left with a question that is closed as "off-topic" because it allegedly asks for "recommendations", leaving future visitors baffled how an obvious scifi story-ID question (admittedly one that asks for two things at a time) can be off-topic here or interpreted as asking for recommendations :-/

Comment: Ideally we should probably reopen this, get @Richard to post his comments as an answer, and then close again as duplicate. But maybe this would be too much fuss?

Comment: @randal'thor - Or you could just flag it for a mod to change the close reason. That's what they're there for.

Comment: @randal'thor - It's two questions, so it is too broad.  I can't VTC again, because it was reopened when it should have stayed closed.

Comment: @Richard Ready for you to post an answer now!

Comment: @mukhujje - I removed the second question because one post can only contain one question.  Feel free to post the part I deleted as its own question.

Comment: @WadCheber The alternative is asking the OP to post their second point as a new question and then dupe-closing that. Asking a question knowing it'll be closed seems a bit ... off. **Edit**: OK, that's exactly what you've just done :-) Fair enough, though there's really no point in the OP posting a new question since they've already got their answer.

Comment: @randal'thor - [Meh](https://static.spiceworks.com/shared/post/0002/5492/grumpy_cat_meh.jpg)

Comment: @randal'thor It may seem off, but in the case of [tag:story-identification] questions I think it makes sense, since the goal of the site is to help people and multiple ways of looking for the same story may help someone in the future.